# Convert GUID to string in SQL Server Reporting Services

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

While trying to display a `GUID` column  in a  report ..its displayed as `#error`..

```
=CStr(Fields!number.Value).ToString
```

I tried the above code in the properties of the column..it doesn't work..

Please advise

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
=CType(Fields!number.Value, GUID).ToString
```

Comment: It works, but why in the name of all that is holy would GUIDs not work with CStr()? Microsoft?! *shakes fist*

Comment: `CType` gives me a squiggly red line in the SSRS expression designer, so I thought this answer was wrong, but the report executes! Microsoft! *shakes fist*

Answer (score 0):

If it is a GUID, just display it without any processing, like other data types.
In case you want to convert it for other purposes, just use ToString, for example:
=IIf(Fields!number.Value.ToString=Fields!ID.Value.ToString, "true", "false")