# How do you check a GUID against a list of known GUIDs in an SSRS expression?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, guid

I was writing an expression in SSRS/Visual Studio 2008, trying to compare a GUID to a list of known GUIDs... however, I was running up against errors in Visual Studio when I attempted that. Here is my code:

```
IIf(Fields!Id.Value = "E1A5AA02-6B0F-4D0D-87B6-E88773314B73" ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took a little digging, and eventually led me to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12079064/convert-guid-to-string-in-sql-server-reporting-services) to find the answer, but I used a combination of string conversion and casing to yield the result:

```
IIf(UCase(CType(Fields!Id.Value, GUID).ToString) = "E1A5AA02-6B0F-4D0D-87B6-E88773314B73" ...
```

For completeness, I probably should have wrapped `UCase` around both sides of the equation, just in case.